# Why it's required to include vector (and other headers too) in global namespace only?

Tags: c++, stl, include, new-operator

This is my sample code and its output.

```
namespace AAA
{
#include <vector>
}

int main()
{
    AAA::std::vector<int> vec;

    return 0;
}

/usr/include/c++/4.9/new:129:41: error: 'void* AAA::operator new(AAA::std::size_t)' may not be declared within a namespace
   __attribute__((__externally_visible__));
```

1. Why isn't allowed to declare operator new/delete in a namespace?
2. Does standard require to include `<vector>` (and other headers too) from global namespace?

Comment: Think twice what that would do. Remember the `#include` directive just expands the text from the included file.

Comment: One question per question.

Comment: I wrote exactly to do what you mentioned - to put vector's code in the namespace.

Comment: ..`operatorew`?

Comment: @user1289 `vector`'s code already is in a namespace. There is no point in nesting it inside another one.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit corrected, thank you

Comment: Please don't taught me that this isn't good practice. I know that there is no meaning in that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, this operator must be at global scope. It is "special".

> `[C++14: 3.7.4.1/1]:` An allocation function shall be a class member function or a global function; a program is ill-formed if an allocation function is declared in a namespace scope other than global scope or declared static in global
>   scope. *[..]*

And, yes, standard library headers must be `#include`d in "free space":

> `[C++14: 17.6.2.2/3]:` A translation unit shall include a header only outside of any external declaration or definition, and shall include the header lexically before the first reference in that translation unit to any of the entities declared in that header. No diagnostic is required.